# How to extract only wanted property from JSON object

Tags: python, json, properties

When I run the code:

```
import requests
import json
def get_fact():
  catFact = requests.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140")
  json_data = json.loads(catFact.text)
  return json_data
print(get_fact())
```

The output is like

```
{'fact': "Cats are the world's most popular pets, outnumbering dogs by as many as three to one", 'length': 84}
```

However I just want the fact.

How do I get rid of the `'fact:'` at the front and `'length:'` at the back?

Comment: `return json_data['fact']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to access the key in the python dict you made with the `json.loads` call. We actually don't need the `json` library as requests can read and deserialize JSON itself.

This code also checks if the response was OK and fails with informative error message. It follows [PEP 20 – The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).

```py
import requests

def get_fact():
    # Get the facts dictionary in a JSON serialized form.
    cat_fact_response = requests.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140")
    
    # Let the response raise the exception if something bad happened to the cat facts server connection.
    cat_fact_response.raise_for_status()
    
    # Deserialize the json (make a Python dict from the text we got). requests can do that on it's own:
    cat_fact_dict = cat_fact_response.json()
    
    # Access the fact from the json from the dictionary
    return cat_fact_dict['fact']

    print(get_fact())
```

When called you get following output as wanted:

```
# python3 script.py 
The cat's tail is used to maintain balance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
you need to use *either* `get_fact()['fact']` or `get_fact().get('fact')`. The former will throw an exception if fact doesn't exist whereas the latter will return `None`.

Why:
In your code sample you fetch some json data, and then print out the entire bit of json. When you parse json, the output is a key/value map called a dictionary (or map or object in other languages). The dictionary in this case contains two keys: `fact` and `length`. If you only one want of the values, then you need to tell python that you want only a single value -- `fact` in this case.

Remember though: this wouldn't apply to *every* json object you read. Not every one is going to have a `fact` key.

Answer (score -1):

To extract `fact` field from the response, use:

```
import requests
import json
def get_fact():
    catFact = requests.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140")
    json_data = json.loads(catFact.text)
    return json_data['fact']  # <- HERE
print(get_fact())
```

Output:

```
Cats have "nine lives" thanks to a flexible spine and powerful leg and back muscles
```

Note: you don't need `json` module here, use `json()` method of `Response` instance returned by `requests`:

```
import requests
def get_fact():
    catFact = requests.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140").json()
    return catFact['fact']
print(get_fact())
```

Comment: proper indenting (4 spaces) could improve your answer

Comment: Clarifying questions like `Are you looking for` are worth to be put as comment before answering.

Answer (score -1):

What you are returning in `get_fact` is a complete JSON object which you are then printing.

To get just its property `fact` (without the length) use a reference to that key or property like:

```
return json_data["fact"]
```

Below is also a link to a tutorial on using JSON in Python:

- w3schools: [Python JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: Although they might help beginners, w3school tutorials are not considered very authoritative. This might be the cause for the downvote.

Comment: Also see how your answer is not different from [Corralien's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72907492/5730279) which also explains that `json` module and conversion is obsolete.